# How to document a variable that isn't really there in Doxygen?

Tags: php, doxygen

For example, I have $theme global variable that is defined in the configuration file, which is not processed by Doxygen. But I want to document it. I tried to do this:

```
/**
 * @var $theme
 * @brief Active theme.
 */
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Does Doxygen support [phpDocumentor's `@global`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.global.pkg.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a doxygen specific file for documenting variables, something like:

### config.dox

```
/**
 * @defgroup configuration Configuration
 */

/**
 * @ingroup configuration
 * @brief Active Theme
 */
$theme;
```

This will create a new Doxygen module named "Configuration" which will contain the variable `$theme`. You could also associate `$theme` with a particular class (use `@memberof` instead of `@ingroup`).