# Document dynamic member variables

Tags: php, doxygen, idiorm

I document model classes (in PHP) with Doxygen. I am using Idiorm & Paris as an ORM and I would like the dynamic member variables (coming straight from the database) also to appear in the generated documentation.

**Example:** I have a model `Group` with some methods like `isMember()` or `users()` documented with Doxygen. In the database I have a table `group` with a field `code` among others. In Idiorm & Paris I can access it from a `Group` instance `$group` like this:

```
$group->code
```

**How can I document `code` in Doxygen?**

**Edit**: This question is similar to [How to document a variable that isn't really there in Doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8883162/220060), but it's about **dynamic members**, not about **variables.**

**Edit 2**: I am unsure about the right terminology. It is a dynamic member variable or a dynamic property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it impossible to document non-existant class variables in Doxygen? I tried a naked

```
/** @var User::email string 
  * Email address
  */
```

without a corresponding `$email;` member variable in the class, but Doxygen valiantly ignored that. I didn't find a command or something to force a documentation of a missing artifact.

Therefore I experimented with **creativedutchmen**'s suggestion, however Paris does not cope well with already existing member variables, because – I think – the PHP magic method `__get()` does not get triggered anymore. I see three possible fixes:

1. `unset()` the documented member variables in the constructor. With `get_class_vars(get_class($this))` this could be done in a parent class. Because my model classes all inherit from a parent class, this would be relatively straightforward.
2. Modify Paris to ignore already set member variables, but I do not see how without `unset()`.
3. Name the member variables slightly differently, like appending an underscore, so they don't conflict with the dynamic variables.

Horrible kludges. To do something at runtime or have additional members to make documentation possible? No thanks.

I decided to leave the situation as-is and document the model factory methods carefully instead. Most of the time the factory methods contains as parameters the class variables to be able to set them. And even if the factory method does not set all class variables, it is possible to document the missing variables in prose. The class documentation is also a good alternative.

I award the bounty to **creativedutchmen** because of thinking out of the box, even if it didn't help me in the end and because I don't want the reputation points to get lost.

**tl;dr**

*Don't kludge. Document dynamic member variables in the factory method or in the class overview.*

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I've done a bit of research myself on Paris, and I think this might help: Paris is indeed using a magic `__get` function, but this shouldn't stop you from doing your magic, if, and this is a big _if_, you declare your property as `private` or `protected`. Of course, this greatly reduces the usability of the generated docs and the code itself, but maybe it is something you can experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

Something I usually do when setting up models for which I know they will contain certain bits of data is setting the variables in the model definition. This makes it easier to see what kinds of data I can expect with the model.

I have no experience with Idiorm nor Paris, but it is something you could try. Documenting the variable is then very easy, because it exists.

Comment: Thanks! Please do test my idea before implementing it - some ORM's support this, other don't.

Comment: It works, but I need to `unset()` the «fake» member variables in the constructor.